# Python - Get an unique integer from 2 numbers

Tags: python, math

I'm making a game (universe, with 'infinite' amount of stars) with procedural generation and I've faced a little problem getting an unique number from coordinates for seed.
The world is divided into 16x16 sectors, and each sector has coordinates X and Y. I use python's module `random` to generate some values by seed (is the sector a star, if so, does it have planets and similar).

Also x and y can be negative numbers.

Here is what I've tried:

```py
random.seed(hash(str((x << 32) + y))) 
#works but very slow

random.seed((x & 0xFFFF) << 16 | (y & 0xFFFF)) 
#also works but if coordinate is bigger than 16 numbers, it just teleports to the center

random.seed(x*y) 
#doesn't work, because coordinates can be x10,y15 and x15,y10, so the number is not unique

random.seed(x * (y << 16))
#the world gets mirrored by half
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: You want one seed number out of two coordinates? How about `16*X+Y` (for zero-based coordinates).

Comment: My idea would be similar to your first one: `random.seed(hash((x, y)))`

Comment: So I tried `16*X+Y` but the world gets mirrored by half because of negative numbers :(

Comment: You could add appropriate values to x and y to make them zero-based and non-negative.

Comment: 16*abs(X)+abs(Y) ?

Comment: What is the domain of *X* and *Y*? Meaning what values can they have? Also why `hash(str())` in the 1st attempt?

Comment: @Nikaido `16*abs(X)+abs(Y)` same. it gets mirrored by quarter

Comment: @CristiFati They can be positive and negative numbers, the world is similar to tile map

Comment: I got that, you already mentioned it. I'm asking about min and max values

Comment: @CristiFati I want to generate the world large as possible, if I use this `random.seed((x & 0xFFFF) << 16 | (y & 0xFFFF))`, maximum coordinate X or Y can be 16 digit number, but I don't like this small limit.

Comment: The question can't be answered unless you specify min and max values for X and Y, the min and max values of the desired output. "A 16 digit number" doesn't really give that information, and if you mean "bits" instead of "digits" then use bits.

Answer (score 1):

Use a complex seed (x = real, y = imaginary).

```
import random as r

x=5.5
y=6.6
sd = x+1j*y
r.seed(sd)
print(r.random())
```